# Run For Loop for a single condition in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am parsing an excel file [session_data,csv], the excel file looks like as follows:

```
Case, StartTime, EndTime
Case_1=Covering 3 time-slots,T00:00:00,T05:00:00
Case_2=Covering multiple time-slots,T00:15:00
Case_3=Covering one time-slot,T00:18:00,T00:47:00
```

I am parsing the file as follows:

```
${LIST}=  Process Data File  ${CURDIR}/session_data.csv   
     : FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
         \    Log    ${LINE}
         \    @{COLUMNS}=    Split String    ${LINE}    separator=,
         \    ${TESTCASE}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    0
         \    ${STARTTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    1
         \    ${ENDTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    2
```

Now I do not need to run the loop for each case but only for a single case where my row (case column) starts with 'Case_2' or 'Case_3'

How can I add that condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that in two ways; the first one would be to filter the records in the `Process Data File` keyword, which is outside the scope of this question.

The other is to force the `FOR` loop to continue - e.g. not execute any more statements, on a condition. This is done by using the keyword [Continue For Loop If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Continue%20For%20Loop%20If) and providing your condition - in this case, the first result of the split to start with that string.

```
: FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
     \    Log    ${LINE}
     \    @{COLUMNS}=    Split String    ${LINE}    separator=,
     \    ${TESTCASE}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    0
     \    Continue For Loop If   not("""${TESTCASE}""".startswith("Case_2") or """${TESTCASE}""".startswith("Case_3"))
     # the following lines will be ran only if the ${TESTCASE} value starts with any of those strings
     \    ${STARTTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    1
     \    ${ENDTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}
     # the rest of your processing logic
```

The condition `not("""${TESTCASE}""".startswith("Case_2") or """${TESTCASE}""".startswith("Case_3"))` is a normal python expression, and `"""` is a "string literal" - thus if the actual value has quote it newline characters, it won't break the expression.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix, I used the keyword "Get Lines Containing String" from Robot library 'String' and removed the "For Loop". To fetch a particular line, I used below code:

```
    ${LIST}=  Process Data File  ${CURDIR}/pricing.csv
    ${LINE}=  Get Lines Containing String  ${LIST}  ${case}
    Log    ${LINE}
    @{COLUMNS}=    Split String    ${LINE}    separator=,
    ${TESTCASE}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    0
    ${STARTTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    1
    ${ENDTIME}=    Get From List    ${COLUMNS}    2
```